# Is there a way to send keyboard input to multiple applications on windows at the same time. (focused and nonfocused windows)

Tags: javascript, python, c, windows

I am looking to build a program that will send keyboard input to multiple windows of the same application at the same time.

I have done a lot of research online and I can't seem to find anything that works.

Is there any line of code/library that can do this for me?

Sorry if I don't have any code to show, this is because I don't. I tried multiple stuff but none of it seems to work.

Comment: Do you know how to send input to one window? Iterate through them and send the same thing to each.

Comment: @RetiredNinja no i don't, it only works on focused windows. i want to work on non focused windows

Comment: Why not having a single background listener that translates key press into socket IPC for all these processes ? you can use something like ZMQ communication models

Comment: @Elbehery i dont want to listen to my key presses. I want the script to read a file, and send keyboard inputs of that file's content to all of the minimized windows.

Comment: The Win32 API should have a function to list all application windows, and another function to report the window state like "minimized", and it has for sure a function to send a message meaning "key press" to any window. -- Go ahead, divide the main task into smaller steps, look for that stuff, and experiment on each of them. This is how development works. -- You can try some "higher level" things like AutoIt which provides a lot of such functions. Well, it's not Javascript or Python... -- Python is known for tons of libraries. Did you look through them?